# Can you create per-user project settings in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

I'm collaborating on an iPhone application, with the project files (`.xcodeproj` directory) checked into source control.  One important setting is the "Code Signing Identity", which specifies the certificates to use to sign the application in order that it can run on the iPhone.

Each developer on the project has his own Code Signing Identity, so whenever anyone makes a change to the project, his Code Signing Identity gets saved into the project settings, and then everyone else inherits that change.  They then have to change that to their CSI before they can continue.

Is there a way to have the Code Signing Identity saved in some local per-user project file that doesn't get checked into source control?

Answer (score 2):

You could base the Xcode project on an .xcconfig file, then make each developer use their own .xcconfig file and keep the identity setting in there.

Answer (score 1):

Either that or have your source control system ignore the file that contains the signature, in git you can create a file called .gitignore, theres probably a similar thing for what you are using. It means even though you've changed it the change won't get mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by making different builds.  The one named "Dev - Rob" had my settings in it, and the one named "Dev - [Other Guy's Name]" had Other Guy's settings.

We also used this to make builds like "Release - Beta" and "Release - AppStore" etc., for all situations where we'd have different signing configurations.